# Getting Product Admin Area URL from code

Tags: magento2, product, admin, url

Inside an observer, I need to get the URL to edit the product in the Admin Area.

Using the following code :

```
$product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product)
```

I get an URL which is not working (and it also have the session value)

http://magento.web/the_admin/catalog/product/view/id/1/s/joust-duffle-bag/key/53cdbf2e9e53cfd4950692664e643710ececac42a2d15156d531dde51454576f/

Which one is the best way to fetch the product URL of the Admin Area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the Edit Product url (catalog/product/edit), you can use the Magento\Backend\Helper\Data::getUrl function.

Include it in your constructor:

```
public function __contruct(\Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper)
{
    $this->backendHelper = $backendHelper;
}
```

Then call getUrl:

```
$productEditUrl = $this->backendHelper->getUrl(
    'catalog/product/edit',
    ['id' => 1]
);
```

This will get you the product edit url for the admin for the product with id 1.